# Get incremental changes for a group using delta query in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I ran the following queries in MS Graph Explorer:

Query1:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group-id]/transitiveMembers

Response includes 2 users:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "id1"
            
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "id2"            
        }
    ]
}
```

Query2:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id  eq '[group-id]'

Response includes 3 users:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=abcd",
    "value": [
        {            
            "id": "[group-id]",
            "members@delta": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "id1"
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "id2",
                    "@removed": {
                        "reason": "deleted"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "id3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what is the difference between these two? I see that 2nd query has 3 users - 2 users + 1 removed user. Is that the only difference?

Also, I see that the response of 2nd query has `@odata.nextLink` and if run `@odata.nextLink` query:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=abcd

I see `@odata.deltaLink` in the response.

```
{{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=xyz",
    "value": [
        {            
            "id": "[group-id]",
            "members@delta": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": "id1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I run `@odata.deltaLink` query:

> "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=xyz"

to see upcoming changes to this group?

Comment: `A group can have users, devices, organizational contacts, and other groups as members` so you can use `groups/[group-id]/transitiveMembers` to get the transitive membership of a group. You can use `/groups/{id}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user` to only get the users which are member of the group. When you use ``/group//delta`, it will give back to you about the  changes of the group, including members newly added/removed...

Comment: Can I use delta query to get transitive membership of a group?

Comment: `Get newly created, updated, or deleted groups, including group membership changes, without having to perform a full read of the entire group collection. See Using Delta Query for details.` from [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you-just a clarification- I want to get  transitive membership of a group (not only the users which are member of the group) using delta query?

Comment: yes you can by using delta query

Comment: Also, can I get @odata.deltaLink when using query1 in my question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raNZk.png  user and group https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWyai.png

Comment: You can test it by yourself.

Comment: @TinyWang I have a group (GROUP 1) containing one user (USER 1) and one group (GROUP 2). GROUP 2 contains 2 users (USER 2 and USER 3). When I run delta query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id  eq 'GROUP 1', response includes USER 1 and GROUP 2. Is there a way to get response as USER1, USER 2, USER 3?

Comment: I'm afraid it can't to be achieved,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tested in my environment and got the same results like below:***

When I executed the **transitive members** query like below, it gives the existing nested members of the group.

[image]

I agree with **Tiny Wang** as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http),

> A group can have users, devices, organizational contacts, and other
> groups as members. This operation is transitive and returns a flat
> list of all nested members

When I executed **delta** query like below, it gives all the members including the removed group members.

[image]

- If you get **`@odata.nextLink`** URL in the response, that means there may be additional pages of data to be returned in the process.
- If you get **`@odata.deltaLink`** URL in the response, that means the existing state of the resource has no more data left to return.
  For future requests, you can use **`@odata.deltaLink`**  URL to know about new changes of the resource .

> The application continues making requests using the  **`@odata.nextLink`**  URL to retrieve all pages of data until a **`@odata.deltaLink`** URL is returned in the response.

**Reference**:

[Use delta query to track changes in Microsoft Graph data - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#use-delta-query-to-track-changes-in-a-resource-collection)

Comment: Thank you so much! To clarify - if I use  delta query on a group, it will return ALL members (NOT just users) with details such as 'deleted'? Could you please confirm the same?

Comment: Yes, when you use delta query on a group, it will return all members in the group with deleted members.

Comment: Thank you! Can I use .Top(n) in the delta query to return n members per page?

Comment: Yes, you can use .Top(n) in the delta query

Comment: Awesome thank you! Also, could you please let me know if these 2 return the same results: graphClient.Groups.Delta().Request().Filter($"id eq '{groupId}'").Top(MaxResultCount).GetAsync(); graphClient.Groups[groupId].TransitiveMembers.Request().Top(MaxResultCount).GetAsync();

Comment: If you are using delta request, you will get removed group members too. But if you are using TransitiveMembers request you will get only existing transitive members of the group.

Comment: Ok so if I use TransitiveMembers request, will it return delta link in the last page response?

Comment: I have an AAD group in which I added 5 users. On running delta link, I see the response showing 5 users. I removed these 5 users from AAD (Note that I removed users from Azure Active Directory). And these users were automatically removed from the AAD group. On running the delta link, I see no response. Is this a bug? Why is the response not showing the removed users?